# D3js, uncaught reference error when selecting rect in selectAll('rect')

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to make a chart. I want users to be able to enter their selections by resizing stacked bars on a single column horizontal column chart.

Bars are stacked and each have .call(drag) event listeners.

This drag event returns an error.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', function() {

        var i = state.interactingWith //i represents current element
        var rects = d3.select('.svg').selectAll('.bar') //Get all stacked bars
        var handles = d3.select('.svg').selectAll('.handle') //Get all event handlers, on the edges of bars
        var currentX = d3.select(rects[0][i]).attr('x')

        d3.select(rects[0][i])
            .attr('width', d3.event.x - currentX)
        d3.select(handles[0][i])
            .attr('cx', d3.event.x)

        if (i < rects[0].length-1){

            var j = i+1 //I want to select the next element, but not if this element is the last
            var currentNextWidth = d3.select(rects[0][j]).attr('width') //This returns the error
            var newNextWidth = currentRightWidth + (+d3.event.x - currentX) 

            d3.select(rects[0][j])
                .attr('x', d3.event.x)                  
            d3.select(rects[0][j])
                .attr('width', newRightWidth)
            questions[i].displayWidth = newRightWidth   

        }
    })
```

Console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null .... d3.min.js:3
```

It says the offending line is `var currentNextWidth ....`

If I replace j with the desired index, it works as expected.
Does anyone have any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned how variable state and state.interactingWith is obtained. Try to put a debug point at offending line and log j, rect[0][j] in console to check these are available in current scope.

Comment: I should have mentioned, state is a global object that contains all chart settings. This was a type issue in the end.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so `state.interactWith` is a string.

I didn't realise `i` was a string, as it works fine by itself. `i + 1` plays up though.

I think what's happened is `i` (string) works as `array['1']` but `i + 1` works as `array['11']`.